# converting timezone to 3 characters ZoneId

Tags: java, timezone

I want to convert TimeZone such as "America/Chicago" to "CST". I can make use of  SHORT_IDS map of ZoneID class. However, there are limited number of timezones configured in that map. What if I want to get "Asia/Hong_Kong" to "HKT", then this map will not get me correct answer.

Is there any library which I can make use of, if something is not provided by Java. I am avoiding creating mapping of these timezones in my application.

Any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what [`SHORT_IDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS) is for: it is a mapping of non-standard IDs. It's in no way intended to be complete, or widely used. As it states in the Javadoc: they are *deprecated* IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TimeZone.getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName-boolean-int-):

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago").getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LIHk2Y)

But be very careful about using three-letter time zone identifiers. *Only* use them for display (as implied by the method name); do not use them to identify a time zone otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible with `ZoneId`?

Comment: ZoneId.getDisplayName.

Comment: Important to note that `getTimeZone` doesn't fail or return null on unknown time zones (it returns GMT).

Comment: `ZoneId.getDisplayName` returns `CT` for *Central Time* for America/Chicago.  Seems fair to me. And HKT for Hong Kong as requested. So I haven’t seen any reason to go back to the outdated `TimeZone` class.

Answer (score 5):

```
    ZoneId hongKong = ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong");
    System.out.println(hongKong.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ROOT));
```

This outputs:

> HKT

Similarly the output for `ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")` is `CT` for *Central Time* (notice that this avoids the hopeless choice between CST for Central Standard Time and CDT for Central Daylight Time).

Please supply your desired locale. In many cases it won’t make any difference, in other cases it will since some time zones have localized abbreviations in some locales.

Unlike the outdated `TimeZone` class the modern `ZoneId` validates the time zone string and throws an exception if it is invalid, so we get a nice chance to correct any errors. For example:

> java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid ID for region-based ZoneId, invalid format: Asia/Hong Kong

### To get the abbreviation for standard time

Edit: In [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62839386/find-standard-time-name-for-a-region-using-java) it was asked to have the abbreviation for standard time (as opposed to summer time/DST). So CST, not CT, for America/Chicago, etc. It appeared that only US time zones needed to be supported. If so, this method does it:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter ZONE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);

private static String getAbbreviationForStandardTime(ZoneId zone) {
    ZonedDateTime timeInStandardTime = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.JANUARY, 1)
            .atStartOfDay(zone);
    if (zone.getRules().isDaylightSavings(timeInStandardTime.toInstant())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Time zones that have summer time on January 1 are not supported");
    }
    return timeInStandardTime.format(ZONE_FORMATTER);
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(getAbbreviationForStandardTime(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")));
    System.out.println(getAbbreviationForStandardTime(ZoneId.of("America/Denver")));
    System.out.println(getAbbreviationForStandardTime(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")));
    System.out.println(getAbbreviationForStandardTime(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
```

Output:

> ```
> PST
> MST
> CST
> EST
> ```

My method includes a check that the time chosen — January 1 — is not in the summer time (DST) part of the year. For many time zones on the southern hemisphere this will fail. If you need to support any of them, the quick fix is to take July 1 instead in those cases.